# Print a carriage return in java on windows on console

Tags: java, windows, newline, carriage-return, system.out

On my OS X machine, the following line gives me a nice and easy way to track the state of my loops:

```
for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++)
    for (int subIndex = index; subIndex < 100; subIndex++)
        System.out.print("\r" + index + "/" + subIndex + "       ");
```

But when I try to run the same thing on windows, it prints out newlines instead of a carriage return. How can I achieve the same simple method of tracking the process on windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the statement and it worked in the command prompt

```
System.out.println("This is Java"+'\r'+"That");
```

and gives me output as

```
That is Java
```

That means it works perfectly.

Note: I run it in Windows 7 with JDK 7 and simple notepad.

It is the problem of eclipse, it will take \r as a new line character and will print

```
This is Java
That
```

as output

Comment: I'm running on Windows XP currently - maybe that makes a difference?

Comment: Through eclipse... On OS X, I use IntelliJ where it works just fine. I'll give it a try on command prompt now.

Comment: As I have already mentioned, problem is with Eclipse not with Java. Without using extra tool like Intellij, it will not work in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Eclipse, you have to enable the control character option on the Console Window.

To enable it, open the Eclipse preferences and select Run/Debug > Console. Then select "Interpret ASCII control characters" and "Interpret Carriage Return (\r) as control character".

Answer (score 0):

By "Windows" you mean `cmd.exe`?  And you want to overwrite to the line you previously output, right?  Unfortunately I think you need to invoke this Win32 API somehow in order to achieve it

- [SetConsoleCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cc429740.aspx)

  - Cf. [Calling Win32 API method from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389156/calling-win32-api-method-from-java)

Maybe other Java gurus can provide better answer ...

Comment: I am running the program in eclipse on a windows machine. Haven't tried it on CMD yet.