# How to execute program from Clojure without any external libraries and showing its output at real time?

Tags: clojure

My attempt:

```
(import 'java.lang.Runtime)
(. (Runtime/getRuntime) exec (into-array ["youtube-dl" "--no-playlist" "some youtube video link"]))
```

I also tried `sh`. But both approaches don't do what I want - running a program similarly like shell does (`sh` waits until program exits, `exec` launches it and doesn't wait for its exit; both don't output anything to standard output). I want live showing of process output, e.g. when I run `youtube-dl` I want to see progress of a video download.

How to do this simple simple task in Clojure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must start the process and listen to  its output stream. One solution is :

```
(:require [clojure.java.shell :as sh]
          [clojure.java.io :as io])

(let [cmd ["yes" "1"]
      proc (.exec (Runtime/getRuntime) (into-array cmd))]
      (with-open [rdr (io/reader (.getInputStream proc))]
        (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
          (println line))))
```

Comment: It's not exactly same as shell does it (e.g. shell allows to "rewrite" current line, so for example progress bar is always shown only once), but it's close enough. Thank you :).

Comment: In my example I just use the println function. For the rewrite behaviour you must implement your own println function that prints the carriage return. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566654/print-a-carriage-return-in-java-on-windows-on-console