# Is there a way to query the windows system for a specific program window in java?

Tags: java, windows

I'm embarking on a project where I need to use the java.awt.Robot class to interact with a program on the Windows OS.

Is there I can query the system for say, a running instance of "notepad" and have it return me the window dimensions? I'm just using "notepad" as an example. I can't discuss the actual program I'm trying to interact with.

I hope the question isn't too vague. If task manager is able to keep a running list of what is happening, then shouldn't I be able to also find my specific program?

**Edit:** Based on the answer I have received so far, I have examined the [calling win32 api method from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389156/calling-win32-api-method-from-java?lq=1) that has been suggested. But I am still vague on how to get the win32 to solve my problem. That thread is asking on how to use dll's.

My problem, as far as I know, is just getting a running instance of "notepad" and then using the win32 api's GetWindowRect method to return me a dimension that I can then use with Robot to tell me where to go. Unfortunately I have no idea on how to do this, I am still fairly new when it comes to Java. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Surely you can do that in C#, dont know about java.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to do.

If you want to get window dimensions, you should recognize that [win32 api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468919(v=vs.85).aspx) can provide that information.

And, if win32 api is providing that information, [how do you call win32 api functions from java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2389156/1273830)? is the question you should be asking.

Comment: Thanks for the direction, I'm still very new with Java so I have yet to understand all of its capabilities.