# Change the language for keyboard with Java

Tags: java

Is there anyway to change the language of the system. Or the Locale of the keyboard with java? I have made a small investigation and it seems like this is not possible with the sdk libraries provided by Oracle. So I assume I have to somehow execute native windows code from Java to do that.

I have the following program which I plan to later make it bootable.
[image]

the selected text is currently displayed  in two languages because I have changed the system's language manualy (or with alt + shift). Can I change the input language from my keyboard only for the running java program on runtime?

Comment: Depending on why you want to do this, the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501842/change-windows-keyboard-in-java) might help you.

Comment: I have updated the question maybe this will help. I have tried the recommended link but it didn't work for me, maybe I have to try more though!