# How to detect when a button has been pressed in an external Java application?

Tags: java, swing

I need to integrate a custom spell-checker into an existing `Java` application without an `Automation API`.

It should work like this:

1. In the external application `A`, the user opens a window, where he/she enters some text. In that window there is a button "Spellchecker".
2. When the user presses the "Spellchecker" button, my program B should read the text from A's text field and put it into the custom spellchecker.

How can I detect that some button has been pressed in an external `Java` application?

**Update 1:** I tried to install my own AWT event listener to detect events in other applications.

```
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new MyAWTEventListener(), AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK);

    while (true)
    {
        Thread.sleep(1);
    }
```

But it doesn't work.

**Update 2:** Replacing the system event queue doesn't work, either.

```
private void queuePushingExperiment() throws InterruptedException,
        InvocationTargetException {
    EventQueue queue = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue();

    queue.push(new MyEventQueue());

    EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("run");
        }
    });
}

public class MyEventQueue extends EventQueue {

    @Override
    public SecondaryLoop createSecondaryLoop() {
        System.out.println("createSecondaryLoop");
        return super.createSecondaryLoop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchEvent(AWTEvent event) {
        System.out.println("dispatchEvent");
        super.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public AWTEvent getNextEvent() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("getNextEvent");
        return super.getNextEvent();
    }

    @Override
    public AWTEvent peekEvent() {
        System.out.println("peekEvent");
        return super.peekEvent();
    }

    @Override
    public AWTEvent peekEvent(int id) {
        System.out.println("peekEvent");
        return super.peekEvent(id);
    }

    @Override
    protected void pop() throws EmptyStackException {
        System.out.println("pop");
        super.pop();
    }

    @Override
    public void postEvent(AWTEvent theEvent) {
        System.out.println("postEvent");
        super.postEvent(theEvent);
    }

    @Override
    public void push(EventQueue newEventQueue) {
        System.out.println("push");
        super.push(newEventQueue);
    }

}
```

**Update 3:** `java.awt.Window.getOwnerlessWindows()` and `EventQueueMonitor.getTopLevelWindows()` both return empty arrays even though there is a `JFrame` open at time of their invokation.

**Update 4:** I noticed that I can't write to the file `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\accessibility.properties` and currently the line `assistive_technologies=com.sun.java.accessibility.AccessBridge` is commented out. That may cause the aforementioned problems with the accessibility objects.

Comment: Can you change the code of A?

Comment: No. If I could, the task would have been very easy.

Comment: That's true. I think all you can do is listen for OS specific messages. For example Windows messages on WIN OSs. That's a really cruel solution, and I am not sure, if java allows this.

Comment: You cannot change the code of A, yet the spell checker is launched by it... They did have to modify A to do that, right? Can't you tell them to copy the text into a file which would be passed as an argument to the spell checker?

Comment: Could you run bth A and B app on the same jvm instance?

Comment: @fge A has a built-in spellchecker (the spellchecker is located in the same code base as the entire code of A), but it doesn't work good enough for my language (Russian).

Comment: @StanislavL How can I achieve this? I thought that for every Java program a separate JVM is launched.

Comment: which `os` do you use?

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry Windows

Comment: Yes if they are run separately it will be. Basically I don't see anyway you can do it in Java. May be in C++ with all the memory manipulations etc. Only way to do so is to ask the people who has original source code to provide an listener registration mechanism. (Observer) which I'm sure you already know... TO sum up, it sucks to be you...

Comment: @LuigiEdlCarno Regarding listening to OS specific messages: I'm not sure that you can control Java applications via WinAPI calls.

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko I think you can do this using JNA. I haven't used them myself yet, but maybe you find something starting [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389156/calling-win32-api-method-from-java). Since the JVM itself converts java calls to OS specific calls, it should produce WINAPI calls, when you exucte A.

Comment: A wild shot here, can you change the startup command? If so maybe it would it be possible to do some load time weaving with AspectJ. If it is then you can hook into the action, if you had the source and knew where to hook in.

Comment: @ShawnVader Rather not. It's not clear whether I can do that (whether the customer will accept it).

Comment: I heard that it is possible to control running Java apps using Java Accessibility. I tried this (see update 1), but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I achieve this? I thought that for every Java program a separate JVM is launched.

Actually java app A could be run from app B. You just call the A's main() method. So in fact you start B.main() which runs necessary B code and then calls A.main() to run A. In this case you can get started window (or frame) using Window class method.

```
public static Window[] getWindows()
```

After that just go down all the subcomponents of the found Window checking their classes and when you find `JButton` check the buton's text or image to find necessary instance. Then just add your listener there.

Comment: Would your approach work, if I write an agent and attach it to the JVM of app A using `com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(...)` ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to implement the example from this tutorial - http://nongreedy.ru/java/2012/10/14/mustangs-attach-api-experiments/ (Russian).

Comment: I see. Russian is ok. Really interesting tool and experiment.